# Comet Chat iOS unresponsive UI issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cometchat

I have integrated Comet Chat  functionality in my application. I am using custom UI for both Group and OneOnOne chat. It's all running fine, but the problem is that when I go to my Group chat screen then my application is becoming unresponsive. It becomes unresponsive when I am scrolling my table.

I had put dispatch functionality in my **CellforRowatIndexPath** for fetching the images link and showing them. For this I am using **SdWebImage** Framework.

Here is my code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"chatroomchatviewcell";
    chatViewCell = [chatTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (chatViewCell == nil) {
        chatViewCell = [[ChatRoomChatViewCellSDK alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    else {
          dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue1 =  dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
        dispatch_async(concurrentQueue1, ^{

        for (UIView *view in chatViewCell.contentView.subviews) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
        });
    }

    /* Define maximum contraints */
    CGSize constraints = CGSizeMake(((self.view.frame.size.width)*2/3 + 8.0f),100000);
    CGFloat wrapperViewX = 0.0f;
    CGFloat wrapperViewWidth = 0.f;
    CGFloat wrapperViewHeight = 0.f;

    NSString *messageString = nil;

    if ([[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:MESSAGE] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {

        messageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:MESSAGE]];
    }
    NSString *nameString = nil;
    NSString *messageType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:MESSAGE_TYPE_KEY]];

    UIView *wrapperView = [UIView new];
    UITextView *textView = [UITextView new];
    UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView new];
    UILabel *nameLabel = [UILabel new];
    UILabel *timeLabel = [UILabel new];

    wrapperView.layer.cornerRadius = 5 ;
    wrapperView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    /* If message is sent by you add Me as the name */
    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"fromid"]] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:LOGGED_IN_USER]]]) {

        nameString = @"Me:";

    } else {
        /* Else append BuddyName in message */
        nameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:",[[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:FROM] capitalizedString]];
    }

    [nameLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.f]];
    [nameLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [nameLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    NSDictionary *attributesName = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.f], NSFontAttributeName, nil];
    CGRect nameRect = [nameString boundingRectWithSize:constraints options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:attributesName context:nil];
    CGSize sizeName = nameRect.size;
    [nameLabel setText:nameString];
    attributesName = nil;

    [nameLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(4.f, 4.f, sizeName.width, sizeName.height)];
    [wrapperView addSubview:nameLabel];
    if ([messageType isEqualToString:MESSAGE_TYPE_IMAGE]) {
        UIButton *btnclk = [UIButton new];
        btnclk.frame=CGRectMake(4.f, 4.f, 100, 100);
        [btnclk setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnclk.tag=indexPath.row;
        [btnclk addTarget:self action:@selector(ShowFullImageVIew:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue =  dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);

        //this will start the image loading in bg
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(4.f, (nameLabel.frame.origin.y + nameLabel.frame.size.height + 4.f), 100.f, 100.f);
        [imageView setFrame:imageRect];
        dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
            NSURL *imgUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:messageString];

            //this will set the image when loading is finished

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (messageString == nil) {

                    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:MESSAGE]]];

                } else {
                    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:messageString]) {

                        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:messageString]];
                    } else {
                        UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
                        activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
                        activityIndicator.color = [UIColor redColor];

                        activityIndicator.center = imageView.center;

                        [imageView addSubview:activityIndicator];
                        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:activityIndicator];

                        [activityIndicator startAnimating];


                        [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:imgUrl completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                          [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];                            
                        }];
                    }
                }
            });
        });





        [wrapperView addSubview:imageView];
        [wrapperView addSubview:btnclk];

        if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"fromid"]] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:LOGGED_IN_USER]]]) {

            if (imageView.frame.size.width > nameLabel.frame.size.width) {

                wrapperViewX = self.view.frame.size.width - imageView.frame.size.width - 14.f;
            } else {
                wrapperViewX = self.view.frame.size.width - nameLabel.frame.size.width - 14.f;
            }

        } else {
            wrapperViewX = 7.f;
        }

        if (imageView.frame.size.width > nameLabel.frame.size.width) {

            wrapperViewWidth = 4.f + imageView.frame.size.width + 4.f;
        } else {
            wrapperViewWidth = 4.f + nameLabel.frame.size.width + 4.f;
        }

        wrapperViewHeight =  imageView.frame.origin.y + imageView.frame.size.height  + 4.f;

    } else if ([messageType isEqualToString:MESSAGE_TYPE_STICKER]) {

        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(4.f, (nameLabel.frame.origin.y + nameLabel.frame.size.height + 4.f), 100.f, 100.f);

        if (messageString == nil) {

            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:MESSAGE]]];

        } else {

            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"StickersFramework.bundle/%@",messageString]]];

        }

        [imageView setFrame:imageRect];
        [wrapperView addSubview:imageView];

        if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"fromid"]] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:LOGGED_IN_USER]]]) {

            if (imageView.frame.size.width > nameLabel.frame.size.width) {

                wrapperViewX = self.view.frame.size.width - imageView.frame.size.width - 14.f;
            } else {
                wrapperViewX = self.view.frame.size.width - nameLabel.frame.size.width - 14.f;
            }

        } else {
            wrapperViewX = 7.f;
        }

        if (imageView.frame.size.width > nameLabel.frame.size.width) {

            wrapperViewWidth = 4.f + imageView.frame.size.width + 4.f;
        } else {
            wrapperViewWidth = 4.f + nameLabel.frame.size.width + 4.f;
        }

        wrapperViewHeight =  imageView.frame.origin.y + imageView.frame.size.height  + 4.f;

    } else {

        [textView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]];
        [textView setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        /* Disable scroll and editing */
        [textView  setEditable:NO];
        [textView setScrollEnabled:NO];

        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        [paragraph setLineSpacing:2.0f];
        NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.f], NSFontAttributeName,paragraph ,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,nil];

        [messageString boundingRectWithSize:constraints options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:attributesDictionary context:nil];

        [textView setText:messageString];

        CGSize sizeMessage = [textView sizeThatFits:constraints];

        textView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,(nameLabel.frame.origin.y + nameLabel.frame.size.height + 4.f), sizeMessage.width, sizeMessage.height);

        [wrapperView addSubview:textView];

        if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"fromid"]] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:LOGGED_IN_USER]]]) {

            if (textView.frame.size.width > nameLabel.frame.size.width) {

                wrapperViewX = self.view.frame.size.width - textView.frame.size.width - 14.f;
            } else {
                wrapperViewX = self.view.frame.size.width - nameLabel.frame.size.width - 14.f;
            }

        } else {
            wrapperViewX = 7.f;
        }

        if (textView.frame.size.width > nameLabel.frame.size.width) {

            wrapperViewWidth = 4.f + textView.frame.size.width + 4.f;

        } else {
            wrapperViewWidth = 4.f + nameLabel.frame.size.width + 4.f;
        }


        wrapperViewHeight =  textView.frame.origin.y + textView.frame.size.height  + 4.f;

        attributesDictionary = nil;
    }

    [wrapperView setFrame:CGRectMake(wrapperViewX, 7.f, wrapperViewWidth, wrapperViewHeight)];


    /* Define timeString & timeLabel */
    NSTimeInterval _interval;
    NSDate *date;

    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"sent"]] length] > 10) {

        _interval = ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"sent"]] doubleValue]/1000);
        date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];

    } else {

        _interval = ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@000",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"sent"]] doubleValue]/1000);
        date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];

    }

    NSDateFormatter *_formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [_formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    _formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    _formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    _formatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;

    NSString *timeString = [_formatter stringFromDate:date];

    [timeLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.f]];
    [timeLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:103.0f/255.0f green:103.0f/255.0f blue:103.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
    [timeLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [timeLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    NSDictionary *attributesTime = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.f], NSFontAttributeName, nil];
    CGRect timeRect = [timeString boundingRectWithSize:constraints options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:attributesTime context:nil];
    CGSize sizeTime = timeRect.size;
    [timeLabel setText:timeString];


    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"fromid"]] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:LOGGED_IN_USER]]]) {

        [nameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [textView setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [wrapperView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:49.0f/255.0f green:140.0f/255.0f blue:231.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];

        [wrapperView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:49.0f/255.0f green:140.0f/255.0f blue:231.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];

        [timeLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - sizeTime.width - 7.f, (wrapperView.frame.origin.y + wrapperView.frame.size.height + 2.f ), sizeTime.width, sizeTime.height)];

    } else {


        [wrapperView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:235.0f/255.0f green:235.0f/255.0f blue:235.0f/255.0f alpha:1.f]];

        [wrapperView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:235.0f/255.0f green:235.0f/255.0f blue:235.0f/255.0f alpha:1.f]];

        [timeLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(7.f, (wrapperView.frame.origin.y + wrapperView.frame.size.height + 2.f ), sizeTime.width, sizeTime.height)];
    }
    [chatViewCell.contentView addSubview:wrapperView];
    [chatViewCell.contentView addSubview:timeLabel];
    return chatViewCell;
}
```

Here I am implementing chat functionality for this we have to update the chat messages on the screen and for this I am using **NsPostNotifictaionCenter**. I am also reloading my table using dispatch in order to avoid Unresponsive UI issue. Here I am posting the code:

```
    - (void)chatRoomMessageUpdateNotifier: (NSNotification *)notification {


        dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue1 =  dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
        dispatch_async(concurrentQueue1, ^{

            if ([[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"TAG"] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
                messageArray = [NSMutableArray new];
                [messageArray removeAllObjects];
                messageArray = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"data"];

                if ([messageArray count] > 0) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                       [chatTable reloadData]; 

                    });



                }

            }
        });

}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. The main problem here is my UI becomes unresponsive. All ideas are totally welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code. If you still face any issue, can you raise a support ticket https://my.cometchat.com/tickets and our team will be happy to assist you further.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"chatroomchatviewcellsdk";
    chatViewCell = [chatTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (chatViewCell == nil) {
        chatViewCell = [[ChatRoomChatViewCellSDK alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    else {
        for (UIView *view in chatViewCell.contentView.subviews) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    /* Define maximum contraints */
    CGSize constraints = CGSizeMake(((self.view.frame.size.width)*2/3 + 8.0f),100000);
    CGFloat wrapperViewX = 0.0f;
    CGFloat wrapperViewWidth = 0.f;
    CGFloat wrapperViewHeight = 0.f;

    NSString *messageString = nil;

    if ([[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:MESSAGE] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {

        messageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:MESSAGE]];
    }

    NSString *nameString = nil;
    NSString *messageType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:MESSAGE_TYPE_KEY]];

    UIView *wrapperView = [UIView new];
    UITextView *textView = [UITextView new];
    UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView new];
    UILabel *nameLabel = [UILabel new];
    UILabel *timeLabel = [UILabel new];

    wrapperView.layer.cornerRadius = 5 ;
    wrapperView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    /* If message is sent by you add Me as the name */
    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"fromid"]] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:LOGGED_IN_USER]]]) {

        nameString = @"Me:";

    } else {
        /* Else append BuddyName in message */
        nameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:",[[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:FROM] capitalizedString]];
    }

    [nameLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.f]];
    [nameLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [nameLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    NSDictionary *attributesName = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.f], NSFontAttributeName, nil];
    CGRect nameRect = [nameString boundingRectWithSize:constraints options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:attributesName context:nil];
    CGSize sizeName = nameRect.size;
    [nameLabel setText:nameString];
    attributesName = nil;

    [nameLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(4.f, 4.f, sizeName.width, sizeName.height)];
    [wrapperView addSubview:nameLabel];


    if ([messageType isEqualToString:MESSAGE_TYPE_IMAGE]) {

        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(4.f, (nameLabel.frame.origin.y + nameLabel.frame.size.height + 4.f), 100.f, 100.f);

        if (messageString == nil) {

            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:MESSAGE]]];

        } else {
            if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:messageString]) {

                [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:messageString]];
            } else {
                [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:messageString] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_avatar_thumbnail"] options:0 andResize:imageRect.size withContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
            }
        }

        [imageView setFrame:imageRect];
        [wrapperView addSubview:imageView];

        if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"fromid"]] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:LOGGED_IN_USER]]]) {

            if (imageView.frame.size.width > nameLabel.frame.size.width) {

                wrapperViewX = self.view.frame.size.width - imageView.frame.size.width - 14.f;
            } else {
                wrapperViewX = self.view.frame.size.width - nameLabel.frame.size.width - 14.f;
            }

        } else {
            wrapperViewX = 7.f;
        }

        if (imageView.frame.size.width > nameLabel.frame.size.width) {

            wrapperViewWidth = 4.f + imageView.frame.size.width + 4.f;
        } else {
            wrapperViewWidth = 4.f + nameLabel.frame.size.width + 4.f;
        }

        wrapperViewHeight =  imageView.frame.origin.y + imageView.frame.size.height  + 4.f;

    } else if ([messageType isEqualToString:MESSAGE_TYPE_STICKER]) {

        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(4.f, (nameLabel.frame.origin.y + nameLabel.frame.size.height + 4.f), 100.f, 100.f);

        if (messageString == nil) {

            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:MESSAGE]]];

        } else {

            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"StickersFramework.bundle/%@",messageString]]];

        }

        [imageView setFrame:imageRect];
        [wrapperView addSubview:imageView];

        if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"fromid"]] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:LOGGED_IN_USER]]]) {

            if (imageView.frame.size.width > nameLabel.frame.size.width) {

                wrapperViewX = self.view.frame.size.width - imageView.frame.size.width - 14.f;
            } else {
                wrapperViewX = self.view.frame.size.width - nameLabel.frame.size.width - 14.f;
            }

        } else {
            wrapperViewX = 7.f;
        }

        if (imageView.frame.size.width > nameLabel.frame.size.width) {

            wrapperViewWidth = 4.f + imageView.frame.size.width + 4.f;
        } else {
            wrapperViewWidth = 4.f + nameLabel.frame.size.width + 4.f;
        }

        wrapperViewHeight =  imageView.frame.origin.y + imageView.frame.size.height  + 4.f;

    } else {

        [textView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]];
        [textView setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        /* Disable scroll and editing */
        [textView  setEditable:NO];
        [textView setScrollEnabled:NO];

        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        [paragraph setLineSpacing:2.0f];
        NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.f], NSFontAttributeName,paragraph ,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,nil];

        [messageString boundingRectWithSize:constraints options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:attributesDictionary context:nil];

        [textView setText:messageString];

        CGSize sizeMessage = [textView sizeThatFits:constraints];

        textView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,(nameLabel.frame.origin.y + nameLabel.frame.size.height + 4.f), sizeMessage.width, sizeMessage.height);

        [wrapperView addSubview:textView];

        if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"fromid"]] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:LOGGED_IN_USER]]]) {

            if (textView.frame.size.width > nameLabel.frame.size.width) {

                wrapperViewX = self.view.frame.size.width - textView.frame.size.width - 14.f;
            } else {
                wrapperViewX = self.view.frame.size.width - nameLabel.frame.size.width - 14.f;
            }

        }
        else {
            wrapperViewX = 7.f;
        }

        if (textView.frame.size.width > nameLabel.frame.size.width) {

            wrapperViewWidth = 4.f + textView.frame.size.width + 4.f;

        } else {
            wrapperViewWidth = 4.f + nameLabel.frame.size.width + 4.f;
        }


        wrapperViewHeight =  textView.frame.origin.y + textView.frame.size.height  + 4.f;

        attributesDictionary = nil;
    }

    [wrapperView setFrame:CGRectMake(wrapperViewX, 7.f, wrapperViewWidth, wrapperViewHeight)];


    /* Define timeString & timeLabel */
    NSTimeInterval _interval;
    NSDate *date;

    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"sent"]] length] > 10) {

        _interval = ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"sent"]] doubleValue]/1000);
        date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];

    } else {

        _interval = ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@000",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"sent"]] doubleValue]/1000);
        date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];

    }

    NSDateFormatter *_formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [_formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    _formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    _formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    _formatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;

    NSString *timeString = [_formatter stringFromDate:date];

    [timeLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.f]];
    [timeLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:103.0f/255.0f green:103.0f/255.0f blue:103.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
    [timeLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [timeLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    NSDictionary *attributesTime = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.f], NSFontAttributeName, nil];
    CGRect timeRect = [timeString boundingRectWithSize:constraints options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:attributesTime context:nil];
    CGSize sizeTime = timeRect.size;
    [timeLabel setText:timeString];

    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"fromid"]] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:LOGGED_IN_USER]]]) {

        [nameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [textView setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [wrapperView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:49.0f/255.0f green:140.0f/255.0f blue:231.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];

        [wrapperView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:49.0f/255.0f green:140.0f/255.0f blue:231.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];

        [timeLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - sizeTime.width - 7.f, (wrapperView.frame.origin.y + wrapperView.frame.size.height + 2.f ), sizeTime.width, sizeTime.height)];


    }
    else {

        [wrapperView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:235.0f/255.0f green:235.0f/255.0f blue:235.0f/255.0f alpha:1.f]];

        [wrapperView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:235.0f/255.0f green:235.0f/255.0f blue:235.0f/255.0f alpha:1.f]];

        [timeLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(7.f, (wrapperView.frame.origin.y + wrapperView.frame.size.height + 2.f ), sizeTime.width, sizeTime.height)];

    }


    [chatViewCell.contentView addSubview:wrapperView];
    [chatViewCell.contentView addSubview:timeLabel];


    return chatViewCell;
}
```

Comment: I have tried ur code but it still freezing ..removed all the dispatces . Followed ur code ,but it still hapening

Comment: Thanks for helping, Mike D! If you are a company and are sharing a Stack Overflow account between employees, it is preferable for you to have individual accounts. This is mainly because we prefer questions and answers not to be signed - that material is often trimmed out by editors (see my edits).